# Orthogonality with regards to norms in real vs complex fields

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, orthogonality

Consider this problem:

*Prove $x$ and $y$ in a complex vector space is orthogonal if and only if $||\alpha x + \beta y|| ^2 = ||\alpha x||^2 + ||\beta y||^2$ for all scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$.*

---

I have solved a similar problem that asks:

*Prove $x$ and $y$ in a real vector space is orthogonal if and only if $|| x + y|| ^2 = ||x||^2 + ||y||^2$.*

I see that since $|| x + y|| ^2 = ||x||^2 + 2<x,y> + \space||y||^2$, if $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal, then $2<x,y> = 0$ and hence $|| x + y|| ^2 = ||x||^2 + ||y||^2$.

I also noticed that if the field is complex, then we could have $2<x,y> = 0$ yet $<x,y> \ne 0$, which would invalidate the second statement.

---

I fail to see how adding a pair of scalars solves the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think that $2 \langle x, y \rangle = 0$ does not imply $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$ for $x, y$ complex?

Comment: $<x,y>= \overline{<y,x>}$. Split $2<x,y>$ into $<x,y> + \overline{<y,x>}$, and the imaginary term cancels out

Comment: @B.Li Why does the imaginary term cancel out? That would be the case for $z + \bar{z}$,  but the second term is not $\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is easy to show that if $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal then
$$\|\alpha x + \beta y\|^2 = \|\alpha x\|^2 + \|\beta y\|^2. \tag{1}$$
Now, let's try to prove that if $(1)$ is true **for all** scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$ then $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal. To this end, we first observe that
$$\|\alpha x + \beta y\|^2 = \|\alpha x\|^2 + \|\beta y\|^2 + \alpha^* \beta x^H y + \alpha \beta^* y^H x. \tag{2}$$
If $(1)$ holds then
$$\alpha^* \beta x^H y =- \alpha \beta^* y^H x. \tag{3}$$
Since $(3)$ holds for all values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, put $\alpha =1$ and $\beta=1$ to get
$$x^H y =- y^H x. \tag{4}$$
Now put $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=i$ to get
$$x^H y =+ y^H x. \tag{5}$$
Solving $(4)$ and $(5)$ simultaneously results in $x^H y = y^H x = 0$.

Q.E.D.

---

Here, $x^H$ denotes the Hermitian transpose of $x$, and $x^H y  = \langle x, y \rangle$.

Comment: i'm not following exactly how $\|\alpha x + \beta y\|^2 = \|\alpha x\|^2 + \|\beta y\|^2 + \alpha^* \beta x^H y + \alpha \beta^* y^H x. \tag{2}$, specifically where the $\alpha^* \beta x^H y + \alpha \beta^* y^H x$ came about.

Comment: @B.Li For a vector $z$, $\|z\|^2=z^H z$. Likewise, $\|\alpha x + \beta y\|^2 = (\alpha x + \beta y)^H(\alpha x + \beta y)$.

Answer (score 1):

First we show that if $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal then 
$$||\alpha x + \beta y||^2 = ||\alpha x||^2 + || \beta y||^2.$$

Assume $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal. Then by definition $\langle x, y \rangle =0.$

Therefore, $ \alpha \beta^{*} \langle x, y \rangle = \alpha^{*} \beta \langle y, x \rangle =0.$

So
$$||\alpha x + \beta y||^2 = \langle \alpha x + \beta y, \alpha x + \beta y \rangle = \alpha \langle x, \alpha x + \beta y \rangle + \beta \langle y, \alpha x + \beta y \rangle$$
$$ = \alpha \alpha^{*}\langle x, x \rangle  + \alpha \beta^{*}\langle x, y \rangle +  \beta \beta^{*}\langle y, y \rangle  + \beta \alpha^{*}\langle y, x \rangle$$
$$= \alpha \alpha^{*}\langle x, x \rangle  + 0 +  \beta \beta^{*}\langle y, y \rangle  + 0 = ||\alpha x||^2 + ||\beta y||^2.$$

Showing the other direction is similar.

Edit:

Note that $\langle x, y, \rangle$ is just some number, so if $\langle x, y, \rangle = 0$ then $\alpha \langle x, y, \rangle = 0$ as well.

For finite dimensional complex vector spaces $\langle x, y \rangle$ is defined:
$$\left [\begin{matrix} x_1 & x_2 & ... & x_{n-1} &x_n \end{matrix} \right] \left [ \begin{matrix} y_1^{*} \\
y_2^{*} \\
\vdots \\
y_{n-1}^{*} \\
y_n^{*}
\end{matrix} \right]
 = x_1 y_1^{*} + ... + x_n y_n^{*}.$$